# Symmetric Matrix and Eigen vector Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a reason as to why the following statement is incorrect?

A matrix A which hits and hangs in n-Dimensions, and if there is basis for n-Dimensions consisting of eigenvectors of A, then A must be symmetric.

I understand that as per spectral theorem, If A is a square symmetric matrix, then there is an orthonormal basis of n-Dimensions consisting of unit eigenvectors of A.

But from the above Spectral Theorem, why can't we conclude that if there is a Matrix A which hits and hangs in n-Dimensions (hence it's a square matrix), and if there is basis for n-Dimensions consisting of eigenvectors of A, then shouldn't A be symmetric? If A is not symmetric, what type of Matrix is it?

I'm a bit confused as to why the reverse is incorrect here?

Comment: What is wrong with saying "a $n\times n$ matrix $A$"?

Answer (score 1):

From the spectral theorem, you don't even have to search for a counterexample. Since the eigenspaces for distinct eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix *must* be mutually orthogonal (since the union of bases of complementary non-orthogonal spaces cannot be an orthonormal basis), a diagonalisable matrix with some mutually *non-orthogonal* eigenspaces cannot be symmetric. Just choose two non-orthogonal line in $\Bbb R^2$, choose distinct eigenvalues to associate to them, then the linear operator with those eigenvalues associated to those lines as eigenspaces will not be symmetric.